# Seperate color for last clicked buttons and visited buttons not visited buttons

Tags: javascript, button, background-color

### Seperate color for dynamically created buttons

```
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.style.backgroundColor = "D3D578";
        btn.setAttribute("id", "btn" + buttonId);
        btn.setAttribute("class", "class" + classId);
        btn.innerText = "click" + buttonId;
        btn.innerText = "click" + classId;
        console.log(btn);
        document.body.appendChild(btn);buttonId++;classId++;
```

Comment: `D3D578` should be `#D3D578`

Comment: Thats right.. Thats for dynamic button... How to diffrentiate the visited and non visited buttons by using color

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be having 2 different CSS classes and managing it with Javascript onClick:

**CSS**

```
.visited-button{
   background-color: #342762; /*visited color*/
}

.normal-button{
   background-color: #ff76aa; /*non-visited color*/
}
```

**Javascript**

```
// your function
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    btn.style.backgroundColor = "D3D578";
    btn.setAttribute("id", "btn" + buttonId);
    btn.setAttribute("class", "class" + classId);

 // Add this here
    btn.onclick=changeButtonColor(btn);

    btn.innerText = "click" + buttonId;
    btn.innerText = "click" + classId;
    console.log(btn);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);buttonId++;classId++;
// end of your function


function changeButtonColor(button){
   button.class = "visited-button";
}
```

Notice that this solution is view scoped. This means that as soon as the user will leave the page and enter again, each button will be un-visited. If you want to do it session scoped (i.e. the buttons will be still visited after refreshing the page) then you will have to handle it server side, storing this information in the session itself or in cookies.

Answer (score 0):

May you can try below option to differentiate the visited and non visited buttons by using color.

**JavaScript**

```js
function generateButtons(totalBtns){
 for(var i=0; i<totalBtns; i++){
   var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.setAttribute("class", "unvisited-color");
    btn.innerText = "clickbtn" + i;
    btn.addEventListener('click', onBtnClick);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
  } 
}
function onBtnClick(event){
 event.target.setAttribute("class", "visited-color");
}
generateButtons(3); //generate buttons dynamically
```

```css
.unvisited-color{
  background-color:#D3D578;
}

.visited-color{
  background-color:#E5E5E5;
}
```